# How to log out of IdentityServer 4 from WebAuthenticationBroker?

Tags: uwp, identityserver4

I have a UWP native client using the WebAuthenticationBroker in the same way that this OidcClient is using it: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/blob/master/Uwp/UwpSample/WabBrowser.cs

The IdentityServer successfully provides the Login form the same way as the Hybrid workflow quickstart sample: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs

Great. That all works fine. Can log in. But when I check the "Remember Me" in the web UI then every time the WebAuthenticationBroker pops up it immediately logs in and disappears. Which is fine until I want it to forget me...

I've read about needing to have the WebAuthenticationBroker initiate a call to the IdentityServer to tell it to logout, so as to clear any cached credentials. But I'm not sure how to do this... Any tips???

(BONUS: And is there any way to do it outside of code with the WebAuthenticationBroker? The windows Credentials Manager does not seem to be helpful for this.)

EDIT: In fact, logout is one thing, removing the cached information from the "Remember Me" checkbox is another...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the IdentityServer sample referenced has a logout prompt enabled by default: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountOptions.cs#L15.

```
public static bool ShowLogoutPrompt = true;
```

So by navigating the WebAuthenticationBroker to the logout endpoint silently it just never was able to get confirmation for logout to occur. See this approach: http://www.cametoofar.com/post/logout-user-from-OpenID-OpenAuth-service-WebAuthenticationBroker-c-microsoft. The key part being:

```
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.SilentMode, new Uri(logout-url-here));
```

Once I turned off the logout prompt it worked...

Good to reference the docs as well: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout.html as it's best to find a way to securely support a user-based logout and an application forced logout.